# Porting FF extension to IE: no global window object in JS WSC

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, bho

I'm trying to port an extension from Firefox to IE. All the extension's code is in JS (no C++ components), so I figured I would reuse the code and only trouble myself with the mozilla specific parts of it (which is no doubt a torture too, but I think it's less painful than rewriting it from the scratch).

The FF extension is wrapped in a JS object that gets initialized during the "load" event. The "business" code of the extension is then fired on "DOMContentLoaded" event.

My original plan was to create a WSC (Window Scripting Component) and listen for onLoad event there and basically do the same thing that the original code does. However, I found out there's no implicit global window object in my JavaScript scripting component,

My plan B was to listen for the "onBeforeNavigate2" event in my C++ BHO code and call the JS WSC code that handles the extension object initialization there. So I decided to pass the browser window object as a "window" parameter to the onBeforeNavigate JS function and rewrite the original extension code to be using the explicit "window" variable instead of relying on the implicit global object.

However, when I handle the "OnDocumentComplete" event (once again listening for it in the BHO and passing the browser window object as an argument to a JS function in the WSC), I get a "Can't execute code from a freed script" error.

The WSC code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<component>
<registration
   ...
>
</registration>
<public>
 <method name="OnBeforeNavigate">
   <parameter name="win" />
 </method>
 <method name="OnDocumentComplete">
   <parameter name="win" />
 </method>
</public>
<script src="sharedjs/foo.js" />
<script language="JScript">
<![CDATA[

var window;

function OnBeforeNavigate(win)
{
   window = win.document.parentWindow.top;
   window.myNS.extObject = initExtensionObject(...);
}
function OnDocumentComplete(win)
{
   window = win.document.parentWindow.top;
   var obj = window.myNS.extObject;
   obj.doTheBusinessStuff();
}
]]>
</script>
</component>
```

I assume that's because the WSC is unloaded after the handler function returns. However, there is a reference to the JS extension object kept in the browser window object, so I would expect the browser to keep the code.

So - what's my mistake here, please?

Cheers,
Tom

PS: WSC stands for Windows Scripting Component

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you targetting?

Comment: 7, 8 and 9. And 6 if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your reference to the window object is no longer valid when the JS finally executes - [What causes the error "Can't execute code from a freed script"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83132/what-causes-the-error-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script)

A couple of things you could try:

instead of `win.document.parentWindow.top`, just use `win.document.parentWindow` which should point to a valid window reference. As where "top" could point to a parent frame or window and you end up with one of the causes in the provided link.

Check to make sure the reference to `myNS.extObject` isn't being destroyed in the bho.  You should probably try catch each statement in `OnDocumentComplete` because either could be giving you the error you're seeing and both have different resolutions.

Finally, if you can, execute the extension using the Context Menu in IE - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735853(v=vs.85).aspx

Then you would have access to the window object via the `external.menuArguments` object in javascript land.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But actually, it was my mistake (and a very lame one I have to say) - I copied and pasted the code for the OnDocumentComplete function and I failed to realize that it was calling CoCreateInstance and creating a new WSC instance. All I needed to do was to keep the reference to WSC in a member variable. Silly me; but I'm a Linux guy in a Win API world and the function names&args scare me. :-)