# Why do I get "Can't execute code from a freed script"

Tags: javascript

First of all: Yes, I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812180/cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script-ie6-ie7-ie8-ie9)... And, Yes, there's no meta after script (as I do not have any meta on my page), and, No, there's no timeout or ajax-request

I have following helper-method (Yes, I could have made a prototype-method ...):

```
function removeElementFromArray(array, compareMethod) {
    if (!array) {
        return;
    }
    if (!$.isFunction(compareMethod)) {
        return;
    }
    var index = getIndexOfElement(array, compareMethod);
    if (index < 0) {
        return;
    }
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
function getIndexOfElement(array, compareMethod) {
    if (!array) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (!$.isFunction(compareMethod)) {
        return -1;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var element = array[i];
        if (compareMethod(element)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I am calling this with:

```
$foo.on('click', function () {
    removeElementFromArray(window.myArray, function (element) {
        return // some condition
    });
});
```

I am getting the exception "SCRIPT5011: Can't execute code from a freed script" (only in IE render-mode < 10) in following line:

```
array.splice(index, 1);
```

But not on the first call, but on any subsequent ones (for the same array) ...

But I can't think of a single reason why this exception occurs, as I am accessing the array in other lines as well in the callstack (as you can see, eg getIndexOfElement, where I iterate over the array).

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle ?

Comment: @dystroy good point! will try to!

Comment: Are you sure none of your code change the splice function ? Is array a real array or an array-like object ?

Comment: @dystroy it's a real array, created with `new Array();` and when I hover the `splice` prototype in the inspector, I get `native code`...

Comment: Do you have any iframes on your page?

Comment: @Tommi ah, good catch on that: actually yes

Comment: Then you definetely should take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83132/what-causes-the-error-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script

Comment: @Tommi: yesssss... I've exchanging the value of the variable in the closure from an iframe, and the original closure then points to something that doesn't exist anymore... please add your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83132/what-causes-the-error-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script) contains a good answers about iframes relationship.
(Added as answer by OP suggestion).