# Power BI Iframe: Issue with IE and Edge

Tags: iframe, powerbi, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, powerbi-embedded

We have an Application Developed in ASP.NET inside which we have added an embedded Power Bi Dashboard using iFrame.

The Dashboard is working as expected in Chrome but facing the following issues with IE and Edge.

1. On IE the Dashboard is not being Displayed when viewed from the Embedded Application and upon clicking the power bi Sign-In button (shown within the Iframe), the application as a whole gets redirected to app.Powerbi.com/.... When you click the back button and refresh, still the sign-in prompt is shown in the iframe.
2. On Edge, the behavior is same as in IE, except that you click the back button from the app.powerbi.com website and then refresh the page, then the report renders correctly within the Iframe.

I tried clearing the Cache and Cookies, tried adding *.microsoft.com site and *app.powerbi.com to trusted sites list(per power bi forums) but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check for the latest Windows updates and try to install it. Then after again try to test this issue on your side.

If the issue persists then hard refresh the page. Clear all the data for that site and again try to load the page.

I tested the issue with **IE 11.1.18362.0** and **Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0**. As per my testing results, both browsers display the Power BI dashboard in ASP.NET site without any issue.

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Output in MS Edge:

[image]

If the issue persists then try to check the console to see whether there is any error or warning message. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I am using IE-11 Version > 11.535.18362.0 (Update Versions: 11.0.165 KB4530677) and Microsoft Edge Version > 44.18362.449.0/Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362 which seems to be a later version than the one you mentioned. I tried following the steps you mentioned on hard refresh/clear cache, but still no luck. I see the below console warning/error in IE11: "DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
SCRIPT5011: Can't execute code from a freed script
reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js (1197,73425)"

Comment: Based on my searching result, it looks like 'SCRIPT5011: Can't execute code from a freed script' is the cause of the issue. The error is caused when the 'parent' window of script is disposed (ie: closed) but a reference to the script which is still held (such as in another window) is invoked. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830442/why-do-i-get-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83132/what-causes-the-error-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script