# freed script with hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-10

I have a page containing an `iframe` in which I expect that within the iframe the user will navigate to many different pages - all of them in the same domain as the parent page.

In the top level window I have a persistent object, let's call it `appData`. And in the iframe I often have lines like

```
parent.appData[someProperty] = {a : 1, b : 2};
```

I'm aware of the general problem of freed script errors and I understand that I shouldn't try to call any arbitrary methods on such an object since the originating document may have unloaded, but surely `hasOwnProperty` shouldn't be such a method, and I should be allowed to say, in some subsequent child page:

```
if (parent.appData[someProperty].hasOwnProperty('a'))
```

Shouldn't I? And here's what's odd: it works as I expect in every browser I've tested except MSIE 10. I did see the recent answer to [IE9 "Can't execute code from freed script" when calling hasOwnProperty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317725/ie9-cant-execute-code-from-freed-script-when-calling-hasownproperty) and indeed using `in` seems to work fine for my case, but I'm wondering whether I've been "cheating" all along or if this is a bug in MSIE 10.

jsFiddle doesn't handle iframes so I'm not sure how best to demonstrate this with an example, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd handle all functions similarly if you are concerned about the freed script issue, including built-in ones such as `hasOwnProperty`.  In that specific case, it still could technically be interpreted as a function on an object, and apparently some browsers treat it as such (IE10) and others treat it as a special case that is still accessible (the others you mention).  Even if it worked in all browsers, I'd still feel wrong about it.

Thus, not sure about your exact case, but could you instead do something like:

```
var appData = parent.appData || {};
var someProperty = appData[someProperty] || {};
if(someProperty[a] !== undefined){
    ..
}
```

Otherwise, you could always surround it with a `try..catch`

**Update**
And of course you could use `in` as well, as mentioned in your linked question.

Comment: Yeah, maybe my intuition is just wrong on this, but my thought was that "just data" isn't subject to the freed script restriction, only "code" is. And `hasOwnProperty` isn't really "part" of the object, by this thought, it's just a method you can call.