# SCRIPT5011: Can't execute code from a freed script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw many post like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408358/cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461506/freed-script-with-hasownproperty)  regarding this type error but in my case i 
have an object in function like below code and i get this error "**Can't execute code from a freed script** "

```
  function updateLetterOfClaim(thisletterClaimID) {

      var updatedLetter = {};

     updatedLetter.new_breaches = top.opener.selected_breach.join(",");//from this line in ie7 i get this error

     updatedLetter.new_causation = top.opener.selected_causation.join(",");

     updatedLetter.new_chronology = top.opener.chronology_records.join(",");

     updatedLetter.new_Injuries = top.opener.damage_records;
}
```

Comment: Show us your [testcase](http://sscce.org)!

Comment: you can test by var a={0:'name',1:'name2'};  then a.join() ; for simple run on your console

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i found the solution thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after see many link and blogs my result come by applying following code

my problem is which i found i apply join() in objects but it apply in array so first i make

my objects in array then apply join  ....

```
 function updateLetterOfClaim(thisletterClaimID) {

            var updatedLetter = {};


            updatedLetter.new_breaches =joinobjects(top.opener.selected_breach);
            updatedLetter.new_causation =joinobjects( top.opener.selected_causation);
            updatedLetter.new_chronology =joinobjects(top.opener.chronology_records);
            updatedLetter.new_Injuries = joinobjects(top.opener.damage_records);
}

  function joinobjects(object){

            return $.map(object, function(v){
                        return v;
                    }).join(', ');
        }
```