# "Can't execute code from a freed script" when calling date.getHours() in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I pass a Date object to a method which calls `date.getHours()` or any other method such as `date.getFullYear()` and it throws an error `"Can't execute code from a freed script"`. It seems that IE9 does not properly support date objects used by date picker.

I'm new to javascript/general coding and have had a problem which only seems to occur in IE9. I am warning everybody about this as I may have gone about solving it in completely the wrong way...

I tried various different things in an attempt to solve this problem, such as:

```
if (date.getHours()=="undefined") {
    var localDate = new Date(date);
    var hours = localDate.getHours();
    // etc 
}
```

I now have a solution (it may not be the best, but it does the job) and will post it below, however I would like to know if anybody else has encountered the same problem and how they have resolved it?

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83132/what-causes-the-error-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the problem happens when the Date object you've got was constructed in a different window, such that since its construction that other window has been closed or reloaded with a new page.

The solution is to send object inter-window in some string form, reconstituting them as necessary in the destination context.

(It isn't just Date instances of course; it's any object type. Primitives don't have the problem, if I recall.)

Comment: Thanks Pointy, this explains a lot! I can't post my solution just yet as I am a new user so must wait 8 hours, but I used a try catch block in a new method which trys to call date.gethours() and then I done exactly that; I reconstructed a new Date object with date which was passed in. This meant that I didn't need to worry about which browser the user was using. Is this the right approach to implement the solution?

Comment: Sure, that'll work. Or you could call `.getTime()` on the original Date and use it to construct a new one in the receiving window context.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was as follows...

I created a new method:

```
function getValidDate(date) {
    try {
        date.getHours();
        return date;
    } catch (e) {
        return new Date(date);
    }
}
```

I then called `getValidDate()` in any method which was affected by the original problem:

```
date = getValidDate(date);
```

It is as Pointy described, I just returned a new Date populated by the original date which had been passed into the method. I could then call any method such as `getHours()`, `getFullYear()` etc on this new date.

I am new to the world of programming so although this might seem simple, I hope this is helpful for others if they are in a similar situation.