# Fail to access backbone events from inside iframe when using IE9/10

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, backbone.js

I have a html page where I define a global `App.vent` backbone event object.

```
var App = {};
App.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

Inside that page, I have an iframe that has a reference to the `App` object.

```
App = parent.App;
```

Code inside the iframe page that makes calls to `App.vent` to trigger an event works fine.  But if the iframe's src changes, then any method invocation on `App.vent` fails and IE gives a

**SCRIPT5011: Can't execute code from a freed script** error.

Any workaround?

Comment: Can you please provide examples of how you are binding to and triggering events? Are you using listenTo() or on()? Are you only receiving events on the page in the iframe, or only triggering from inside the iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a very good example of why this occurs in this following answered question:

[What causes the error “Can't execute code from a freed script”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83132/what-causes-the-error-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script)

In particular check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84300/1439720) by Sjoerd Visscher as it both outlines your problem and shows a workaround.

Lastly, it would be much better form to ensure that you keep track of your event binding and remove any bindings to functions that were contained in iframe content that no longer exist. This is a memory leak and good practice is to control these sorts of things.

Comment: Yeah, I read that link above before posting, but didn't find anything helped.  Your last comment is what I was thinking about after I posted, so yeah, I had to stop listening to the events that I used listenTo() on.