# Angular 5 (IE11) Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

I am having trouble with IE11 in Angular 5 a couple of days. I have turned on polyfills:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

and set meta tag for IE:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Everything is working when I start project with **ng serve**. But when I build project with **--prod** option, app is not working in IE11. Firefox and Chrome are working fine.

Console log:

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'gui/account'
    Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'gui/account'
       at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8080/gui/main.d12ff1833b14b6308efb.bundle.js:1:401190)
       at e.prototype.error (http://localhost:8080/gui/main.d12ff1833b14b6308efb.bundle.js:1:386643)
       at e.prototype._error (http://localhost:8080/gui/main.d12ff1833b14b6308efb.bundle.js:1:7955)
       at e.prototype.error (http://localhost:8080/gui/main.d12ff1833b14b6308efb.bundle.js:1:7661)
       at e.prototype._error (http://localhost:8080/gui/main.d12ff1833b14b6308efb.bundle.js:1:7955)
       at e.prototype.error (http://localhost:8080/gui/main.d12ff1833b14b6308efb.bundle.js:1:7661)
       at e.prototype._error (http://localhost:8080/gui/main.d12ff1833b14b6308efb.bundle.js:1:7955)
       at e.prototype.error (http://localhost:8080/gui/main.d12ff1833b14b6308efb.bundle.js:1:7661)
       at e.prototype._error (http://localhost:8080/gui/main.d12ff1833

SCRIPT5011: Can't execute code from a freed script
File: polyfills.6460c1711c3b9abc371d.bundle.js, Line: 1, Column: 69035
```

When I try to debug it, I get some error in polyfills.bundle.js:

[IE11 debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcD55.jpg)

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: This looks like it is rooted in this same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83132/what-causes-the-error-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the error "Can't execute code from a freed script"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83132/what-causes-the-error-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out what caused this problem. I was serving Angular app from Spring application **webapp/gui folder**. This caused router to behave strange and solution was to change **base href** in index.html from

```
<base href="#/">
```

to

```
<base href="/gui/">
```

This way my Angular Spring controller will redirect link http://localhost:8080/gui/account to Angular index.html. Then Angular router will pick up this link and redirect to /account component.

This is maybe related to a defect https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18176 .

I hope this will help you guys also.

Comment: Thanks dude. i have just used '<base href="/subdirectory-Name/">' for IE11

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue only with IE11 using Angular 6 and Spring boot

I solved the problem using my own factory to provide the `APP_BASE_HREF` token based on the current location `window.location.pathname`:

```
{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: window.location.pathname,
}
```

I also removed the `<base href`> tag from `index.html` just to keep it concise.

See [IE11 Route Issue with sub-folder relative base path](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18176)

See [my source code](https://github.com/eljaiek/oralia-build)