# React - cannot parse Error when using Promise with Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, promise

I'm pretty new to React and I don't undestand what's happening there.

I have a search bar that allows me to search a user by name.
If some users match, then I need to open a modal with the results.
If an error occurs, then I need to open a custom Error modal with a message that changes according to the error type.

Here's my function :

```js
 const onSearchUser = (userName: string): void => {

  searchUser(userName)
        .promise.then(result => {
          // show users modal
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
          const response = e.response.data
          if( 'errorType' in response ) {
               // should open an modal with a specific error message
          } else {
               // should open another modal with another error message
          } 
        })
  }
```

**On chrome :**
The modal shows up in every cases.

**On edge:**
I get a `can't execute code from freed script`

So, after trying to remove some lines of code (just for test), my guess it that the error comes from

`const response = e.response.data`

because the modal is actually displayed if I change the code into :

```js
 const onSearchUser = (userName: string): void => {

  searchUser(userName)
        .promise.then(result => {
          // show users modal
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
          showModalError(true, 'some message');
        })
  }
```

The `console.log(e)` gives the following stack trace :

```
[object Error]: {description: "Unable to get property 'status' of undefined or null reference", message: "Unable to get property 'status' of undefined or null reference", number: -2146823281, stack: "TypeError: Unable to get property 'status' of undefined or null reference at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:681:3) at tryCatcher (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:57710:9) at Promise.prototype._settlePromiseFromHandler (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:55826:9) at Promise.prototype._settlePromise (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:55883:13) at Promise.prototype._settlePromise0 (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:55928:5) at Promise.prototype._settlePromises (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:56004:13) at _drainQueueStep (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:52778:9) at _drainQueue (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:52771:9) at Async.prototype._drainQueues (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:52787:5) at drainQueues (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:52700:9)"}
description: "Unable to get property 'status' of undefined or null reference"
message: "Unable to get property 'status' of undefined or null reference"
number: -2146823281
stack: "TypeError: Unable to get property 'status' of undefined or null reference at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:681:3) at tryCatcher (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:57710:9) at Promise.prototype._settlePromiseFromHandler (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:55826:9) at Promise.prototype._settlePromise (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:55883:13) at Promise.prototype._settlePromise0 (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:55928:5) at Promise.prototype._settlePromises (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:56004:13) at _drainQueueStep (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:52778:9) at _drainQueue (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:52771:9) at Async.prototype._drainQueues (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:52787:5) at drainQueues (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:52700:9)"

__proto__: Object
```

But if I display the response body from the  network tab, I have :

```js
{
  errorType : "ERR103",
  message : "Too many results"
}
```

If I do the same on Chrome, I get the same result in the NETWORK tab, but the console gives :

```
Error: Request failed with status code 502
    at createError (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:51423:15)
    at settle (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:51685:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:50888:7)
From previous event:
    at xhrAdapter (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:50839:10)
    at dispatchRequest (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:51489:10)
From previous event:
    at Axios.request (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:51265:23)
    at Axios.<computed> [as get] (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:51280:17)
    at Function.wrap [as get] (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:51856:15)
    at get (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:694:62)
    at searchLegalEntities (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:256:66)
    at onSearch (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:3212:81)
    at onSearch (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:9171:14)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:96780:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:96829:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:96884:31)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:96898:25)
    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:97028:3)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:97053:5)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:97157:5)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:97166:10)
    at forEachAccumulated (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:97138:8)
    at runEventsInBatch (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:97183:3)
    at runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:97324:3)
    at handleTopLevel (http://localhost:8000/assets/main.bundle.js:102247:5)
```

So my questions are :

1. Do I get the "can't execude code from freed script" because the "errorType" property does not exist in my response ?  I though this error occurs when a child component is using some piece of code of a parent component that no longer exists..
2. How is it possible to have a difference between Chrome and Edge ?
3. Am I catching the error the right way  ? How to solve my issue ?

Thanks.

**EDIT** Here is the full code :

```js
export const SearchUserHeader: FC = () => {
  const style = useStyles()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined)
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [userList, setUserList] = useState<UserList | undefined>(
    undefined,
  )
  const [modalError, setModalError] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined)

  const searchUserAction = (value: string): void => {
      setLoading(true)
      setOpen(false)
      searchUsers(value)
        .promise.then(result => {
          setModalError(undefined)
          setUserList(result)
          setOpen(true)
        })
        .catch(e => {
          const response = e.response.data
          if ('codeError' in response) {
            const error = response as SearchUserError
            if (['ERR13', 'ERR14'].includes(error.codeError)) {
              setError(error.message)
            } else {
              error.codeError === 'ER09'
                ? setModalError(error.message)
                : setModalError('user-technical-error')
              setUserList(undefined)
              setOpen(true)
            }
          } else {
            setModalError('user-technical-error')
            setUserList(undefined)
            setOpen(true)
          }
        })
  }

  const onKeyPress = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    setValue(e.target.value)
    setError(undefined)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header>
        <div className={style.children}>
          <SearchBar>
            onClick={searchUserAction}
            onChange={onKeyPress}
            value={value}
            error={error}
            loading = {loading}
          />
        </div>
      </Header>
      {
        <UserResults>
          open={open}
          setOpen={setOpen}
          result={userList}
          errorMessage={modalError}
        />
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
export const UserResults: FC<{
  open: boolean
  setOpen: (v: boolean) => void
  result?: UserList 
  errorMessage?: string
}> = ({ open, setOpen, result, errorMessage }) => {
  const styles = useStyles()
  return (
    <Modal open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
      <div className={styles.modalContainer}>
        <div className={styles.modalContent}>
          <div className={styles.header}>
            <div className={styles.title}>
              {` (${
                result !== undefined && result.length !== undefined
                  ? result.length
                  : 0
              })`}
            </div>
            <Button
              className={styles.closeButton}
              onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
              icon={<Icon name="cross" />}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.body}>
            {errorMessage === undefined && Array.isArray(result) ? (
              result.length > 0 ? (
                <ModalContent setOpen={setOpen} list={result} />
              ) : (
                <div className={styles.infoMessage}>
                 No results
                </div>
              )
            ) : errorMessage == 'user-technical-error' ? (
              <ErrorHeader
                open={true}
                message={i18n('user.search.error')}
              />
            ) : (
              <div>{errorMessage}</div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Comment: 1. No, the problem is specific to things that weren’t presented in this code, can be a modal or else, here’s an explanation of this error, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83132/what-causes-the-error-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script 2. You refer to old Edge, correct? Because new Edge is supposed to work the very same way 3. It’s unknown because you omitted relevant parts of your case, it depends on what an error may look like, if it doesn’t have “response” it will obviously fail. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for your problem.

Comment: @EstusFlask just edited my question.

Comment: It still doesn't contain searchUsers. The question doesn't mention Axios, while you use it. Problems I see here are that you access `e.response.data` without checking that `response` and `response.data` exist. If `e` is not Axios error it will fail. And investigate `Unable to get property 'status' of undefined`, it's specific to Axios and may happen because of various things that weren't shown in the question like interceptors. Currently only you can debug the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved by replacing bluebird polyfill by  es6-promise