# Angular interactivity issues on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, angular-material, internet-explorer-11, polyfills, zone

The angular app basically becomes non interactive in some parts when fired up on IE 11.
Mouse events are not working . Mouse events such as Hover, Click etc all are unresponsive.
Although the elements are accessible using the Tab/ Shift +Tab and work as expected.

I have already tried by uncommenting everything in *polyfills.ts* file and installing the relevant packages as mentioned in the file and as given on the Angular github
(https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/MODULE.md)

Also, the *browserlistrc* file has the IE9-11 versions enabled/configured

I wont be able to provide some relevant screenshots/demo as its client confidential.
Can someone suggest what could possibly be wrong ? We are trying to narrow down our issue and pin point the root cause.

Environment Setup :
Angular Version : 11
Node Version : 14
Npm Version : 6

Package Json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "mobx": "^4.11.0",
    "ngx-markdown": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.3",
    "ngx-translate-multi-http-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-virtual-scroller": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "sass": "^1.32.12",
    "sass-lint": "^1.12.1",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "tinycolor2": "^1.4.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.12",
    "@angular/cli": "11.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "autolinker": "^1.8.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "d3": "^5.9.1",
    "interactjs": "^1.3.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^11.2.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.39.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint-sonarts": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  }
```

Comment: If you open the IE11 browser console, do you see any errors?

Comment: Without any real error messages, the root issue is IE11, see: [Microsoft 365 apps say farewell to Internet Explorer 11 and Windows 10 sunsets Microsoft Edge Legacy](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/microsoft-365-apps-say-farewell-to-internet-explorer-11-and/ba-p/1591666)

Comment: @JSONDerulo I checked it ! Just got it once . This is the issue : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31723.

Comment: Is `Can't execute code from a freed script` the only issue in console? If so, have you tried the solution in the github link to see if it can fix the issue? I also find [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83132/what-causes-the-error-cant-execute-code-from-a-freed-script) which explains the cause of the issue. Besides, you need to **target es5** to make Angular 11 work in IE11, you can refer to [this article](https://dev.to/coly010/angular-how-to-support-ie11-4924).